# select default row where product missing for the week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
product weekend month   Qty
a   20210618    202106  10
b   20210618    202106  10
c   20210618    202106  10
a   20210611    202106  10
c   20210611    202106  10
```

How to get result like below

`SELECT` statement result should be (product b was missing for 20210611 weekend so a default row with 0 as qty in select statement for that weekend)

```
Product weekend month   Qty
a   20210618    202106  10
b   20210618    202106  10
c   20210618    202106  10
a   20210611    202106  10
b   20210611    202106  0
c   20210611    202106  10
```

Comment: Seems like you need a `CROSS JOIN` between your `Product` and `Weeks` table, and then `LEFT JOIN` to your data.

Comment: Yes you are right Larnu Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to bring in the existing data:

```
select p.product, wm.weekend, wm.month, coalesce(t.qty, 0) as qty
from (select distinct product from t) p cross join
     (select distinct weekend, month from t) wm left join
     t
     on t.product = p.product and t.weekend = wm.weekend and
        t.month = wm.month;
```

This version uses `select distinct` to get the products and time periods from the table itself.  You may have other sources for this information -- such as a separate product table or a calendar table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct product, distinct weekend to arrive at combination of product, weekend. Later, find if quantity is present for the combination or not.

```sql
declare @table table(product char(1), weekend date, month   varchar(6), Qty int)
inSert into @table values
('a','20210618','202106',  10),
('b','20210618','202106',  10),
('c','20210618','202106',  10),
('a','20210611','202106',  10),
('c','20210611','202106',  10);

;WITH ProductWeekCombination as
(select product, weekend FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT product from @table) as p
CROSS JOIN 
(select distinct weekend from @table) as w
)
SELECT pw.product, pw.weekend, ISNULL(ot.Qty,0) as qty from ProductWeekCombination as pw
OUTER APPLY (select QTY FROm @table as t where  t.product = pw.product and t.weekend = pw.weekend) as ot
order by product, weekend
```

| product | weekend | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2021-06-11 | 10 |
| a | 2021-06-18 | 10 |
| b | 2021-06-11 | 0 |
| b | 2021-06-18 | 10 |
| c | 2021-06-11 | 10 |
| c | 2021-06-18 | 10 |

Comment: @deeSQL, If it answers your question, please mark it as answer. so, it will be helpful for others in future.